# How to specify SQL Server CE database size while opening connection through ADO using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-ce

I have a piece of code which pulls all the data from a SQL Server CE database to Excel. This works fine for small databases (less than 250 MB) but when handling large DB (in my case it is 1.24GB), the ADO connection state is not open.

How can we specify the Max Database size=2047 in connecting string? Here is the one which I tried but that didn't work.

```
stConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Max Database Size=2047; Data Source= " & Filepath & " ;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ssce: in front of SQL CE specific connection string keywords:

```
Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;ssce:Max Database Size=2047;Data Source= " & Filepath & " ;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Comment: I was waiting for your reply. Still it is not working, connection state is showing as 0.

Comment: Do you get any errors ? Sounds like you are just inspecting the connection state...